# ReOrder List in NativeScript Vue

Tags: nativescript-vue

I'm pretty new to nativescript-vue, but I got an app to display a nice list as fetched from an api.

Now I'd like to be able to have the user reorder it.

The documentation seems aged, so I'll just post this example of a list that at least displays, though cannot be reordered:

```
 <template>
 <Page class="page">
    <ActionBar title="ListView with Avatars/Thumbnails" class="action-bar" />
    <ScrollView>
        <ListView for="item in items" class="list-group" @itemTap="onItemTap">
            <v-template>
                <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="*" columns="auto, *">
                    <Image row="0" col="0" :src="item.src" class="thumb img-circle" />
                    <Label row="0" col="1" :text="item.text" />
                </GridLayout>
            </v-template>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { text: "Bulbasaur", src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png" },
        { text: "Charmander", src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/4.png" },
        { text: "Charizard", src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/6.png" },
        { text: "Squirtle", src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/7.png" },
        { text: "Wartortle", src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/8.png" },
        { text: "Blastoise", src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/9.png" },
        { text: "Caterpie", src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/10.png" },
        { text: "Weedle", src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/13.png" },
      ]
   }
  },
  methods: {
    onItemTap: function(event) {
      console.log("You tapped: " + this.$data.items[event.index].text);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

The docs suggest that it should be easy: [Item Reorder](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/ListView/item-reorder). But I'm not getting the pieces to fit together. So maybe we can get some concise code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use the `<RadListView>` component instead of the `<ListView>`. Then, all you need is to add the attribute `itemReorder="true"`. Like so:

```
<RadListView for="item in items" class="list-group" @itemTap="onItemTap"
            itemReorder="true">
```

You can find your example working in [this playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=jdQR5Q).

Also, the Vue docs for the RadListView are located [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/item-reorder). These Vue docs are not as complete, but everything should work once you "translate" to Vue.

Comment: Thanks, Tiago. Yep, RadLustView was what I wanted, but everything I tried threw an error. The playground example gave the same error:

Comment: Did you test the playground example in your phone? It is working here. It is not `<lv:Radlistview>`, but `<RadListView>`.

Comment: Yes, I viewed your comment on my phone. When I clicked the link, it opened preview and threw that error (timestamped just now).

Comment: However when I viewed the playground on my laptop, and scanned the qr code with my iPhone, it worked. I also had recreated this as a new project, with success, until I tried to follow the directions in the docs. Let me fiddle again.

Comment: Are you installing the RadListView plugin as instructed here: https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/getting-started?

Comment: I was never able to successfully install and use RadListView in a clean app. (Is it that I'm on Windows?). But I downloaded the playground here, built my code into it, and success! Thanks, Tiago. Really appreciate your patience.