# Drag and Drop with Nativescript Vue

Tags: nativescript-vue

I want to make a to do list with nativescript vue and I want the user to be able to change the order of list items by dragging them.

Does anyone have a resource that I can reference that would help me out? Or anything that would put me on the right path.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the RadListView with `itemReorder="true"`. E.g.

```
<RadListView for="item in items" class="list-group" @itemTap="onItemTap"
        itemReorder="true">
```

See these instructions on [how to install the plugin](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/getting-started).

See this working example [on playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=jdQR5Q).

Comment: Thank you so much! This should be just what I was looking for. I will give it a go within a week.

The playground example is really helpful and the pokemon data is a bonus :)

Comment: Hello, I have not been able to get this to work yet. I installed the plugin, added the import, and I told Vue to use it.

When I try to navigateTo the page with the RadListView, nothing happens on the emulator. I even copy and pasted your exact hello world component, and I get the same results. 

If I change the RadListView to a normal ListView, the navigateTo does change the page and lists out all of the pokemon, but if I switch it back to RadListView, nothing happens.The console does say CreateElement(nativescriptscrollview) and CreateElement(NativeRadListView) though.

Comment: I am sorry it's not working for you. Can you create a playground with your code?

Comment: This is part of a decent sized app so I am trying to figure out how to replicate it in the playground.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally changed your playground app.js file. I have since forked your project and have started making changes on my own playground.

Comment: I have not had success making this into a playground. I could add you as a collaborator on github if that works (the project is currently in a private repo), but I understand if you are not interested since that is a lot of extra steps/work.

Comment: Rob, did you have any success? Getting back to this, I'm totally confused by all the competing documentation sources out there.

Comment: For example, Tiago links instructions for "How to Install the Plugin", but the first step there is to modify a main.ts or main.js file. I don't seem to have one of those in my app.

Comment: You are probably using an outdated template. Do you see an `app.js`? That should be your main file.

Comment: Thanks, I added the import code to app.js, and the app ran. (just not yet reorder). Which is older: app,js (the reorder example template) or main.js (the installation instructions here https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/getting-started ?

Comment: I recommend creating NativeScript-Vue projects with [these instructions](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/), which use the `main.js` as the entry point. There is no problem if your app uses app.js as an entry point, though. This is a NS config in `app/package.json`.

Comment: The example playground no longer works for either Android or iPhone.

Comment: weird... I didn't touch it... Anyway, it's fixed now: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=jdQR5Q&v=4.

Answer (score -1):

Rob, I'm trying to do the same thing: [ReOrder List in NativeScript Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109656/reorder-list-in-nativescript-vue). [RadListView Item Reorder](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/item-reorder#radlistview-item-reorder) seems to be the intended solution. So far, though, I'm having trouble with the instructions.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. It looks like you are on the right track with those links. 

The playground example that Tiago included looks like it will be really helpful for us.